# SQL Server order by in procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query which works fine in SQL Server:

```
SELECT InvoiceID, SUM(UnitPrice)
FROM Sales.InvoiceLines
GROUP BY InvoiceID
ORDER BY InvoiceID
```

When I put it in a procedure the `order by` clause is not accepted:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ReportsSales
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN (
        SELECT InvoiceID, SUM(UnitPrice)
        FROM Sales.InvoiceLines
        GROUP BY InvoiceID
        ORDER BY InvoiceID)
END;

EXEC dbo.ReportsSales;
```

Why is that and is there any recommended way of dealing with it?

Comment: Move set nocount on inside of the begin, and remove the parentheses around the query?

Comment: Lose the brackets after `BEGIN` and before `END` - not needed, not supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not use round brackets around the `SELECT` in the procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ReportsSales
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT InvoiceID, SUM(UnitPrice)
    FROM Sales.InvoiceLines
    GROUP BY InvoiceID
    ORDER BY InvoiceID;
END;
GO

-- execute it
EXEC dbo.ReportsSales;
```

Then you should be fine.